# Insert multiple rows using triggers using three tables

Tags: sql, triggers

```
ALTER TRIGGER tr_ItemAccessInsert
ON [dbo].[tbl_InventoryGroup]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ID decimal(18,3), @InventoryID decimal(18,3)

    SELECT @ID = [ItemID] FROM [dbo].[tbl_ItemMain]

    SELECT @InventoryID = [GroupID] FROM inserted

    INSERT INTO tbl_ItemInventoryAccess ([ItemID], [InventoryID], [Value])
    VALUES (@ID, @InventoryID, '0.11')
END
```

this is my query for trigger
i have 10 item in tbl_itemmain so i want to insert all the 10 itemsid in the tbl_inventoryacess please help me with that

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product and triggers are vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: take care inserted table can hold more than 1 record!

Answer (score 0):

You would just use `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into tbl_ItemInventoryAccess ([ItemID], [InventoryID], [Value])  
    select i.??, i.GroupID,  '0.11'
    from inserted i;
```

It is unclear how `ItemId` is determined.  I imagine that a table called `tbl_ItemMain` has more than one row.  Perhaps you can just use `i.ItemId`.

Answer (score 0):

if i am using like
Alter trigger tr_ItemAccessInsert
on [dbo].[tbl_InventoryGroup]
After insert
as begin
Declare @ID decimal(18,3),@InventoryID decimal(18,3)

select @InventoryID=[GroupID] from inserted

insert into tbl_ItemInventoryAccess([ItemID],[InventoryID],[Value])  values((select  itemid from tbl_ItemMain) ,@inventoryid,'0')

end

getting an error subquery returned more than one value